# How to multiply value in table

Tags: sql

I have a problem because I would like to multiply the NPV value * the rate on the day it is. A multiplies me by all the dates in the rate table. And I would like for example for the NPV position in 04/01/2015 to multiply by the rate on this date. and not the entire table.

```
proc sql;
    create table tmp_cirs_kurs as
    select a.*,
           b.KURS
    from tmp_cirs a
    left join kursy b on a.WALUTA=b.WALUTA and a.DATA_DANYCH=b.DATA_DANYCH
;
quit;
proc sql;
    create table cirs as
    select 
            a.DATA_DANYCH,
            a.DATA_MATURY,
            a.DATA_START,
            a.ID,
            a.INSTRUMENT,
            a.WALUTA as WALUTA_REC,
            b.WALUTA as WALUTA_PAY,
            a.KURS as KURS_REC,
            b.KURS as KURS_PAY,
            a.NOMINAL_REC,
            b.NOMINAL_PAY,
            a.NPV as NPV_REC,
            a.NPV*a.KURS as NPV_REC_PLN,
            b.NPV as NPV_PAY,
            b.NPV*b.KURS as NPV_PAY_PLN
    from 
            ( select * 
              from tmp_cirs_kurs
              where WALUTA ne "PLN") as a
    left join 
            ( select * 
              from tmp_cirs_kurs
              where WALUTA eq "PLN") as b
    on a.ID=b.ID
    order by a.ID
;
quit;
```

This is sample kurs table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUBnp.png)

Comment: Using `(b.NPV*b.KURS)                as NPV_PAY_PLN` should work no ?

Comment: nothing change :(

Comment: What is the data type of columns `NPV` and `KURS` ?

Comment: Its is numeric NPV and KURS

Comment: You're not matching on date.

Comment: @shawnt00 how to do that ?

Comment: None of this query makes sense. Why is there a weird self join for instance? If you want to filter on a date then add it to the appropriate subquery/subqueries or include it as a join condition.